# Get JSON value in PHP using different if conditions

Tags: php, json

There is JSON with the following result:

```
0
Area : Market
Fruit : Apple
Colour : Red
Price : 5

1
Area : Shop
Fruit : Apple
Colour : Red
Price : 4

2
Area : Market
Fruit : Apple
Colour : Green
Price : 3
```

I'd like to get the price of the 'Green' 'Apple' bought in 'Market', that is 3 EUR.

Could you give me some help how to use 'foreach' and 'if' formulas in PHP for the result?

```
foreach ($myJson as $key => $value) { 
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
        if ((($k=='area') AND ($v=='market'))) {
            echo $v;
        } 
        if ((($k=='colour') AND ($v=='green'))) {
            echo $v;
        } 
        if ((($k=='fruit') AND ($v=='apple'))) {
            echo $v;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `@Atti` take help from my answer.

Comment: You're in luck, because @anantkumarsingh is too good for you. Questions like these are bad questions, because you haven't tried anything yourself. You've shown no code, no thought process, absolutely nothing. You're asking SO to do your work for you -- and that's not how it works here. Please remember that for in the future :-)

Comment: You're right, I tried with foreach key and val but it does not lead to the result. I don't wanna lead you to the wrong direction with this:

foreach ($myJson as $key => $value) { 
   //echo "<h2>$key</h2>";
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
    if ((($k=='area') AND ($v=='market'))) {echo $v;}
    if ((($k=='colour') AND ($v=='green'))) {echo $v;}
    if ((($k=='fruit') AND ($v=='apple'))) {echo $v;}
    
     //echo "$k | $v <br />"; 
    }
   }

Comment: @Atti let me tell you either you have wrong code  but please put that it in your code. it make others to feel that at-least you tried and they will happy give you answer. since this one is easy to handle that's why you got answer. but if it is complex one. you will face -ve marking and also no answer. Please be careful in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php
$json_array = json_decode($json); // suppose your json data variable name is $json then decode it and assing to a new variable $json_array

foreach($json_array as $json_arr){ // now iterate through that array
    if($json_arr['Area'] == 'Market'&& $json_arr['Fruit'] == 'Apple' && $json_arr['Colour'] == 'Green'){ // check all conditions
        echo $json_arr['Price']; // if all true then print value.
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Nice & Clear solution. Thanks your quick answer. :)

Comment: thanks for marking. glad to help you. if possible vote-it up also. thanks.:):):). have a happy day.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
<?php
$json_array = json_decode($json, true); 

  for ( $i=0; $i < count(  $json_array ); $i++ ) // All elements are reviewed
          { 
           if($json_array[$i]['Area'] == 'Market' && $json_array[$i]['Fruit'] == 'Apple' && $json_array[$i]['Colour'] == 'Green') // check condition
                     { 
                echo $json_array[$i]['Price']; // IF TRUE, PRINT PRICE
                          }
             } 
 ?>
```